# java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException:attempting to castjar: javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am running below rest API in my code and it gives me the below error. I am not sure whether this is an issue with the jar. Please help me .

```
java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/wtpwebapps/searchextractweb/WEB-INF/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class to jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/wtpwebapps/searchextractweb/WEB-INF/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class
    javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:146)
    javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:120)
    javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:179)
    com.sun.jersey.api.client.PartialRequestBuilder.type(PartialRequestBuilder.java:92)
    com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.type(WebResource.java:343)
    com.tlr.searchextract.workflow.Workflow.retrieveSearchInfo(Workflow.java:1208)
    com.tlr.searchextract.workflow.Workflow.createWorkflowRequest(Workflow.java:275)
    com.tlr.searchextract.messages.SearchExtractEventHandler.createNewWorkflowRequest(SearchExtractEventHandler.java:675)
    com.tlr.searchextract.messages.SearchExtractEventHandler.processRequest(SearchExtractEventHandler.java:134)
    com.tlr.searchextract.messages.SearchExtractEventHandler.processMessage(SearchExtractEventHandler.java:65)
    com.tlr.searchextract.messages.MessageHandler.routeMessage(MessageHandler.java:92)
    com.tlr.searchextract.messages.MessageHandler.processMessages(MessageHandler.java:64)
    com.tlr.searchextract.servlet.RequestModel.insertCurrentRequest(RequestModel.java:190)
    com.tlr.searchextract.servlet.SEControllerServlet.insertRequestTemplate(SEControllerServlet.java:1344)
    com.tlr.searchextract.servlet.SEControllerServlet.performTask(SEControllerServlet.java:1941)
    com.tlr.searchextract.servlet.SEControllerServlet.doPost(SEControllerServlet.java:90)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I have the below code for executing REST API

private void retrieveSearchInfo() {
//      find out what type of workflow to create
searchType =
document
.getElementsByTagName("search.type")
.item(0)
.getFirstChild()
.getNodeValue();
try {
excludeMetaDoc =
document
.getElementsByTagName("exclude.metadoc")
.item(0)
.getFirstChild()
.getNodeValue();
} catch (Exception e) {
excludeMetaDoc = "";
}
try {
searchGroup =
document
.getElementsByTagName("search.group")
.item(0)
.getFirstChild()
.getNodeValue();
} catch (Exception e) {
searchGroup = "";
}

```
try{
imageDoc =
    document
        .getElementsByTagName("search.imagedoc")
        .item(0)
        .getFirstChild()
        .getNodeValue();
}catch (Exception e) {
    imageDoc = "";
}       

//add the term "search" to the value of the searchLevel
//vaiable in order to fit the needs of the LTC request
searchLevel =
    document
        .getElementsByTagName("search.level")
        .item(0)
        .getFirstChild()
        .getNodeValue();

if (searchLevel.equalsIgnoreCase("collection set")) {
    searchLevel = "collectionset";
}

//collection or collection set name
searchName =
    document
        .getElementsByTagName("search.name")
        .item(0)
        .getFirstChild()
        .getNodeValue();

searchNovusVersion =
    document
        .getElementsByTagName("search.novus.version")
        .item(0)
        .getFirstChild()
        .getNodeValue();

searchNovusEnvironment =
    document
        .getElementsByTagName("search.novus.environment")
        .item(0)
        .getFirstChild()
        .getNodeValue();

//check to see if the user wants either all of the guids
//for a collection or a collection set  
if (searchType.equalsIgnoreCase("all guids")
    || searchType.equalsIgnoreCase("document count")) {
    if("Norm".equalsIgnoreCase(searchGroup))
        queryText = "=n-relbase";
    else
        queryText = "=n-document";

    queryType = "boolean";

} else {

    queryText =
        document
            .getElementsByTagName("search.query.text")
            .item(0)
            .getFirstChild()
            .getNodeValue();

    //escapte special characters
    //      escape any reserved characters
    // Problem using an ampersand (&) in the Search query.  Maestro translates it to an entity in the relevant data.  Need to use the word "and". 
    queryText = escapeXML(queryText, "&", "and");
    //          queryText = escapeXML(queryText, "&", "&amp;");
    queryText = escapeXML(queryText, "<", "&lt;");
    queryText = escapeXML(queryText, ">", "&gt;");
    queryText = escapeXML(queryText, "'", "&apos;");
    queryText = escapeXML(queryText, "\"", "&quot;");

    //find the search type boolean or natural
    queryType =
        document
            .getElementsByTagName("search.query.type")
            .item(0)
            .getFirstChild()
            .getNodeValue();
}

try {
    searchOutputResource =
        document
            .getElementsByTagName("search.output.resource")
            .item(0)
            .getFirstChild()
            .getNodeValue();

    searchOutputPath =
        document
            .getElementsByTagName("search.output.path")
            .item(0)
            .getFirstChild()
            .getNodeValue();

    searchOutputPrefix =
        document
            .getElementsByTagName("search.output.file.prefix")
            .item(0)
            .getFirstChild()
            .getNodeValue();

} catch (Exception e) {
    searchOutputResource = "";
    searchOutputPath = "";
    searchOutputPrefix = "";

    if (searchOutputPrefix != null) {
        if (searchOutputPrefix.length() == 0) {
            searchOutputPrefix = "se";
        }
    } else {
        searchOutputPrefix = "se";
    }
    //e.printStackTrace();
}

//now get the resource signon and password

String output="";

try {

    Client client = Client.create();
    System.out.println("resourceName: "+searchOutputResource);
    WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/searchextract/webapi/resource?isGroupAndResource=true&groupId="
                + requestGroup + "&resourceName=" + searchOutputResource);

    ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
if (response.getStatus() != 200)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
         + response.getStatus());
}

output = response.getEntity(String.class);

    ResultSetIterator rsi = new ResultSetIterator(output);

    searchOutputResourceUser = rsi.getFieldValue("resource_signon");
    searchOutputResourcePass = rsi.getFieldValue("resource_password");

} catch (RemoteException re) {
    System.err.println(re.detail.getMessage());
    if (re.detail.getMessage().indexOf("DuplicateKeyException") > -1) {
        //throw new Exception("Duplicate record");
    }
} catch (NamingException e) {
    System.err.println("NamingException: " + e.getMessage());
    System.err.println("Root cause: " + e.getRootCause());
    System.err.println("Explanation: " + e.getExplanation());
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

}

Below is the pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tlr.searchextractproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tlr.searchextractproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>searchextract</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>searchextract</name>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
</dependency>
        
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
           <version>1.2</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
         <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
         <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
      
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
  <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0.1</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.39</version>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>  
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm/com.ibm.mqjms -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mqjms</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.resource/connector -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.resource </groupId>
    <artifactId>connector</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>



<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>



<dependency>
   <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
   <artifactId>com.ibm.dhbcore </artifactId>
   <version>7.1.0.0</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>searchextract</finalName>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This exception is thrown while executing the below line
ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class)
I am using Java 8 and Tomcat 8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException RuntimeDelegate.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278027/java-lang-linkageerror-classcastexception-runtimedelegate-class)

Comment: Nope. JAX RS API I am using is in Java 8 and it should work. And the error message is really annoying.

Comment: Try remove depenency of tomcat in pom.xml, maybe it work. There are 2 overlapping classes. One at tomcat, and one at the war file

Comment: yes. I removed that but encountered some other error below

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$Closure
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at com.tlr.searchextract.workflow.Workflow.retrieveSearchInfo(Workflow.java:1203)
 at

Comment: Are you share this project in githud

Comment: No. This is not in GitHub

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? It's pretty much the same error messages for me, but with jakarta and using Gradle.

Answer (score 6):

I have faced the same error with my code and could resolve by using jersey dependency version 2.34

*POM dependency*

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

*My Error Message*

```
2021-09-22 08:32:23.839 INFO 10 --- [http-nio-9070-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/faw-qa-api/target/faw-qa-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class to jar:file:/faw-qa-api/target/faw-qa-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class] with root cause

java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/faw-qa-api/target/faw-qa-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class to jar:file:/faw-qa-api/target/faw-qa-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:105)
```

I updated the dependency version of jersey-client and jersey-common to 2.34 and the issue was resolved.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.34</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: does here java version matters ?

Comment: It should not matter ideally. At the time of posting my comment, I was using Java 8. Now updated to jave 17 and it is still working for me! Please note that now I am using version 2.35 inplace of 2.34

Comment: okay great, with java17 I am facing some issues. let me check again with 2.35, if that helps. Thanks for your comment.